# Rotate Logs of systemd-journal-remote

Tags: journald, centralized-logging

I am running Ubuntu 22.02 with `systemd-journal-remote` version `249.11-0ubuntu3.6.` The hard drive was full because log rotation was not set-up. To manage file size of journals I updated my config at `/etc/systemd/journal-remote.conf.d/01-central-log.conf` with the two attributes `MaxFiles` and `MaxUse`. Unfortunately these attributes are not respected and the following error is thrown when I restart the systemd-journal-remote service:

```bash
Jan 27 10:20:11 log-server systemd-journal-remote[949021]: /etc/systemd/journal-remote.conf:18: Unknown key name 'MaxUse' in section 'Remote', ignoring.
Jan 27 10:20:11 log-server systemd-journal-remote[949021]: /etc/systemd/journal-remote.conf:18: Unknown key name 'MaxFiles' in section 'Remote', ignoring.
```

I have also tried updating `/etc/systemd/journal-remote.conf` directly. Same outcome

Here is my config at `/etc/systemd/journal-remote.conf.d/01-central-log.conf`

```bash
#  This file overrides /etc/systemd/journal-remote.conf

[Remote]
# keep only 20 journal files as we have 20 logging servers
# MaxFiles only effects archives. Journal files that are used are not deleted!
MaxFiles=20
# Limit size of Journals to 20GB in total
MaxUse=20G
```

I have found and verified that the attribute is `MaxUse` and not `SystemMaxUse` as it is for the system wide setting. Found in the manual [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journal-remote.conf.html) and also in [source](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/journal-remote/journal-remote.conf.in).

Can someone help me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from a user of the systemd newsgroup. The configuration attributes are correct and placed in the right files.

Trouble is, as he mentioned that the [freedesktop man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journal-remote.conf.html) "reflect either the latest state of the main branch, or the newest tag". So the website shows a documentation of a version that is not being shipped yet by Linux distributors.

So for anyone running into an issue as I did: Respect the appropriate man page version of your installed systemd software rather than using freedesktop man page: `man journal-remote.conf`